# Build xcconfig from podspec using exact version of dependency

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

The ParcelKit [Cocoapods podspec file](https://github.com/andygeers/ParcelKit/blob/9c0d293dc72f5a4e2d65cbfff106ff4574645512/ParcelKit.podspec) defines a dependency on the Dropbox Sync API SDK like so:

```
s.dependency 'Dropbox-Sync-API-SDK', '~> 3.1.0'
```

At the moment, this means it fetches version 3.1.1 of the SDK (it's ambivalent about the final part of the version number - which is a *good* thing!). But the same podspec also then adds an entry to the Framework search paths of the xcconfig file using a hardcoded version number, `3.1.0`:

```
s.xcconfig = { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_ROOT}/Dropbox-Sync-API-SDK/dropbox-ios-sync-sdk-3.1.0"' }
```

This causes a compilation error, because it looks for v3.1.0 and ignores what is actually installed, v3.1.1, so it can't find the header files and everything breaks.

Obviously we can manually update the ParcelKit podspec (and indeed, it has already been updated to explicitly reference v3.1.1) but I wondered if there's a more robust way to define this so that if Dropbox ever releases v3.1.2 then the podspec continues to work automatically? i.e. that it will automatically add 3.1.2 to the Framework search paths rather than 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a version like this remove the `~>`.

```
s.dependency 'Foo', '3.1.0'
```

The different ways to specify a version are explained [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod)

Comment: I think I expressed my question poorly then - I *like* that it's pulling down 3.1.1, I just want to make sure that it's that version that gets added to my Framework path rather than the 3.1.0 that I specified (but I don't know in advance *exactly* which version will get pulled down)

Comment: Ah yes. So why do you have to add the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` in this case? It seems like that should be up to the linked Dropbox spec.

Comment: Dropbox isn't installed via the spec - this *is* the spec that installs the Dropbox library file

Comment: This should be handled entirely by the fact that this spec depends on the Dropbox spec which vendors its  framework with `vendored_frameworks`. You should try removing this `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` portion of the spec and the linking should still work.